# I miss vs I am missing

Tags: usage

Teachbook issue:

> I (to miss) your excellent cooking!

Why "I miss" in the book answers mentioned instead of "I am missing"?

Comment: There are any number of forms of the verb that could fit into that sentence. Among them are (1) I **miss** your cooking, (2) I **am missing** your cooking, (3) I **missed** your cooking, (4) I **was missing** your cooking, (5) I **will miss** your cooking, and (6) I **will be missing** your cooking. What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare the choices:

1. I miss your excellent cooking! (simple present)

or

2. I am missing your excellent cooking! (present continuous)

The first sentence is preferred. The second one sounds like something a foreign speaker would say.

Why?

Part of the reason might be "that's just how it is, in English", but it can be analyzed further:

The simple present verb tense means "in general".  So, "usually, often, always, in general, I miss your cooking."

The present continuous means "an activity at this moment". So, "right now, I am missing your cooking.  But not yesterday, or last week. Not tomorrow, and not next week. Only right now."

Which would you rather imply about their cooking? Wouldn't it be a much nicer complement to say you always miss them? That may explain why the simple present is used in this case.